# Find the limit of the sequence $\sqrt{2} ,\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}} , \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}} ,.....$ = ?

Tags: calculus

find the lim of the sequance when n $\to \infty  $

$\sqrt{2} ,\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}} , \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}} ,.....$

Comment: **Hint:** Take logarithms.

Comment: Let $x=\sqrt{n\sqrt{n\sqrt{n}}}...$. Then you have $x=\sqrt{n x}$ or $x^2=n x$ which gives you $x=n$ for any $n$, including $n=2$